# SQL Server Compact 4.0 private deployment with Entity Framework 6.0 and NuGet

Tags: deployment, sql-server-ce, nuget-package, entity-framework-6

I have standardly setup WPF project with Entity Framework 6 and SQL Server Compact 4.0 installed. 
When I build my project all the necessary files for SQL Server CE deployment are correctly copied to the `Release` folder, including `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll`.

But running project on a machine without SQL Server Compact installed throws `System.IO.FileLoadException`.

In my development environment is the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` loaded from GAC. I have found this reference, where the version numbers of dlls are explained: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg213826.aspx

I supposed that the version of `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` assembly form NuGet is 4.0.0.0.

So I have manually changed `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` reference in my project to 4.0.0.1 file form the Private folder and copied `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` 4.0.0.1 to the production machine.

I have changed `app.config` like that:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Now I get this exception on development machine:

> The connection given is not of type 'SqlCeConnection'.

On production machine I get `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException`.

Is there any chance to get private deployment working with NuGet and EF 6? Or is it necessary to copy manually all the files in x86, amd64 folders?

Comment: You need to install the EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact 6.0.1 package, whcih creates relevant settings in app.config. And you cannot use the 4.0.0.1 version, but must use 4.0.0.0 assembly version. I will create a new blog post the deals with EF6 and SQLCE 4 private deployment.

Comment: Thank you very much for a quick response! That would be great. I have the mentioned package installed. I use Entity Framework reference both form Client and Model projects. Still I cannot understand why I get System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException with 4.0.0.0 reference in app.config; and I cannot event see any further detail of the exception.

Comment: Maybe you can use this blog post as inspiration: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/10/sql-server-compact-4-desktop-app-with.html ?

Comment: Yes, those are great posts, but why should I copy all those SQL CE files when all the mentioned files are already there copied form NuGet package. Is it because of assembly version of files other than System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll? I believe I am struggling with the problem what actually my bin/release folder, my references and config file should look like, so that I can simply copy the content or use ClickOnce.

Comment: No. The blogpost describes ClickOnce/xcopy, so to speak.

Comment: It seems that System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException is already another problem - in config. This change in DbProviderFactories should be sufficient. Stil the app does not work, but problem is elsewhere, I will report back later, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException` was already problem within my app, I also forgot to change DB name after deployment.

I have followed this guide and it is working now:

http://erikej.blogspot.sk/2013/11/entity-framework-6-sql-server-compact-4_25.html